# How can I use the broken bar (¦) in GCC?

Tags: c

I'm trying to code in C with the bit operator 'or' (`¦`) (quite simple, I know).

However, when I compile it in GCC, I get:

```
error: stray \302 and stray \246
```

I tried to look for a solution to this problem, and all that I saw was that this error happens when the compiler doesn't recognize the symbol.
What can I do to make it work?

My code is:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int x, y , z;
  x = 0xffff;
  y = 0x8888;
  z = x ¦ y;
  printf("0x%u \n", z);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the error on the terminal:

```
ex_8_4.c: In function ‘main’:
ex_8_4.c:19:3: error: stray ‘\302’ in program
   z = x ¦ y;
   ^
ex_8_4.c:19:3: error: stray ‘\246’ in program
ex_8_4.c:19:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘y’
   z = x ¦ y;
            ^
```

Apparently I used the wrong symbol (¦ instead of |) (for some reason that's how it's appear in the book), so now it's working.

Comment: it's not the same char as `|`. Re-type it.

Comment: You should use the pipe `|` character.

Comment: Please cut and paste any error messages directly into your question, rather than link images of your terminal.

Comment: There is no such operator in the C language.

Comment: There isn't any need to retype anything. A direct analysis is: 302 246 (octal) → 0xC2 0xA6 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+00A6 ([BROKEN BAR](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)). It can be searched for (and replaced) using regular expression `\x{00A6}` in any modern text editor or IDE (note: The notation is different in Visual Studio Code (and probably others): `\u00A6` (instead of `\x{00A6}`)).

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: Correction (URL): [BROKEN BAR](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `¦` is not correct bitwise or operator. Search for this `|`  in your keyboard.
This code compiles well in my machine with `|`.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int x, y , z;
    x = 0xffff;
    y = 0x8888;
    z = x | y;
    printf("0x%u \n",z );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong character. 
You should use:     `|`

So, your code should look like this:

```
#include "stdio.h" 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{ 
     int x, y, z; 
     x = 0xffff; 
     y = 0x8888; 
     z = x | y; 
     printf("0x%u \n", z); 
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I'd also change the header to `<stdio.h>`, and remove `main()` parameters (since they're not used).

Comment: @pmg: The signature of `main` is fine. Note that an empty argument list is an obsolecence feature. If no arguments are used, `int main(void)` should be used.

Comment: Adding void as parameter list is what I meant to say.

Comment: I focused on question (which char to use)... Of course, your comments are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the proper character (`|` vs `¦`), use the [trigraph](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1.1) `??!`.

Your line would look like this

```
z = x ??! y;
```

Comment: Trigraphs are a desperation measure, not least because you have to explicitly enable them with GCC using `-trigraphs` (and you might need `-Wno-trigraphs` too).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: my GCC (version 4.9.2) compiles cleanly with `-std=c89 -pedantic`.

Comment: If you add `-Wall`, I believe you'll get a warning.  Using GCC 7.1.0: `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -c cox.c` yields:
`cox.c:3:1: error: trigraph ??= converted to # [-Werror=trigraphs]` and
`??=include <stdio.h>` identifying the line with the trigraph.  So do versions 5.2.0 and 6.1.0.  Without the `-Wall`, they aren't worried about the trigraphs.  (I don't happen to have a GCC 4.x on this machine.)  I don't compile without `-Wall` (or `-Werror` or `-Wextra`).